# How do you effectively destroy Blastpopoulous?

Tags: bloons-monkey-city

I have been playing Bloons Monkey City (B.M.C.) and there is this boss called Blastpopulous and he just kept throwing fireballs and stunning my dartling gun. It took me 3 tries just to beat him lv.1, and I gained nothing other than a couple of bloonstones. Is there a strategy that can destroy him in 1 or 2 tries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Boss_Bloon/Strategies#Blastapopoulos:_Demon_of_the_Core

There are a few strategies on the wiki, but here is the main one, paraphrased a bit from the source.

**Phase One:**

> Start by placing a 0/0 [Mortar Monkey](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Mortar_Monkey) aimed at the first bend, a 0/4 [Dart Monkey](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Dart_Monkey), and as many other 0/0 Dart Monkeys as you can afford. Start the round, and then immediately use the Fan Club ability. Once it wears off, **quickly** sell it and upgrade another to 0/4, then use the ability again. After two ability uses, you should have enough money to sell the 0/4 Dart Monkey and then buy a 1/4 [Spike Factory](https://bloons.fandom.com/wiki/Spike_Factory) and use its ability.
>
> Once you can do this, Phase One is over. Sell off all your dart monkeys and mortar (but not too fast or else you might crash your game).

**Phase Two:**

> Sell/rebuy Spike Storm as fast as possible. If your micro is sufficient enough, you should have around $100K by the time Blastapopoulos reaches the top right corner of the screen.

**Phase Three:**

> Build two villages in the far right side of the screen. Upgrade one to 0/4 and one to 4/0. Then place all of your 1/4 Spike Factories in the nearby bend and use **ALL** of the abilities whenever possible. If you need to, sell off your Spike Factories and move them to the next bend (once again supported by two villages). If your micro is fast enough, you will win!

Comment: They cant access the wiki!